# 404 Not Found PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to access remote data with Curl or file_get_contents, but they both return 404 Not found. The same link in browser and on different server works. Maybe something is disabled in php config?

Here is the same function with Curl and file get contents:

```
    public function getNowPlaying() {

    $source = "http://v12.radionsm.lv/lv/stats";//$this->url . "/lv/stats";

    $ch = curl_init($source);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if (curl_exec($ch) === FALSE) {
        die("Curl error: " . curl_error($ch));
    }
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

    $data = array(
        'status' => (string) $xml->status,
        'onAir' => (string) $xml->dj_name,
        'artist' => (string) $xml->artist_name,
        'title' => (string) $xml->song_name,
        'albumArt' => (string) $this->medium($xml->song_pic)
    );

    return $data;
    }

    public function getNowPlaying() {

        $source = "http://v12.radionsm.lv/lv/stats";
        echo file_get_contents($source);


    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Have you tried using wget or curl on the command line to get this URL?  Perhaps the issue is the DNS on the machine on which you are running your PHP code.

Comment: Its Unix, but can't say wich distro. And I have no access to console.

Comment: You're calling curl_exec() twice there, which will cause you to retrieve the same page twice in rapid succession, BTW.

Comment: And if you've got PHP, [you've got access to the console](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler added that check to see if curl returns error, wasn't there before.

Comment: @Raimonds: You should assign the value to $data, then check $data, not call the function twice.

Comment: called `echo shell_exec("curl http://v12.radionsm.lv/lv/stats");` but it doesn't return anything. I feel so dumb :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is some kind of protection from auto scrapping. So you need to repeat browser behaviour to get read that page.

Try to set up CURLOPT_REFERER with valid homepage url. You need to send everyone header in your curl request, which is sent by browser.

Comment: Im sending  private $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1"; But will try referer (:

Comment: Still returns 404, and forgot to mention it works with other adreses, like it returns google and other, but not this.

Comment: @Raimonds: Sounds like somebody blackholed requests from that server--perhaps because during development you started hitting that URL a little too often.

Comment: @Raimonds check one by one headers sent by browser and headers sent by your curl request. When you create exactly the same request, which is sent by browser, you will get curl working.

Comment: If this process is not automated, than its not possible, because its on the same server, just different domain. And I have premission from owner.

Comment: @Eugene Manuilov Sorry How do you check what headers are sent?